Changing Folder Icons on Desktop doesnt work
I want to change some Folder Icons, but on the Folders which are on Desktop it doesnt work.
To change the Icon of the Folders inside the Home Folder is possible, but the Home Folder itself can not be changed to another Icon..
Is this somehow possible? Because if i click on Properties it shows that the Home Folders Icon can be changed, but when i quit after changing Icon, the Folder stays the same.
If i create a new Folder at Desktop, i can also not be changed, if i create a new Folder insinde Home, it can be changed.
I use Ubuntu 24, yaru theme

Folders on the desktop are managed by a dedicated Gnome Shell extension. Likely, that extension does not (yet?) support changing icons.

Okay, how is that Extension called?
